# Perl code modifie logs

Tags: perl

I want to program a perl script to change logs format. I want to remove --- from logs. Then separate the CRLF by |.

basically I want to obtain this result :

```
INFO|[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'|JB173F3N|17/02/15 14:32:03:930|Inbound Message | ID: 5 Response-Code: 200 | Encoding: UTF-8 | Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 | Headers: {connection=[close], Content-Length=[650], content-type=[application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Tue, 17 Feb 2015 13:32:03 GMT], Server=[Apache], X-Powered-By=[Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1]} | Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> | <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><con:Reponse xmlns:con="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/smc/consultation"><con:IdPRM>19136758109411</con:IdPRM><con:CR><dico:Statut xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico">Rejet</dico:Statut><dico:HorEmission xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico">2015-02-17T14:32:03.887+01:00</dico:HorEmission><dico:Detail xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico"><dico:Code>REJ016</dico:Code></dico:Detail></con:CR></con:Reponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Instead of this One:

```
INFO|[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'|JB173F3N|17/02/15 14:32:03:930|Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 5
Response-Code: 200
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Headers: {connection=[close], Content-Length=[650], content-type=[application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8], Date=[Tue, 17 Feb 2015 13:32:03 GMT], Server=[Apache], X-Powered-By=[Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1]}
Payload: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap:Header/><soap:Body><con:Reponse xmlns:con="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/smc/consultation"><con:IdPRM>19136758109411</con:IdPRM><con:CR><dico:Statut xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico">Rejet</dico:Statut><dico:HorEmission xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico">2015-02-17T14:32:03.887+01:00</dico:HorEmission><dico:Detail xmlns:dico="http://www.erdfdistribution.fr/linky/types/dico"><dico:Code>REJ016</dico:Code></dico:Detail></con:CR></con:Reponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

My code doesnt do this, it makes something like clustering in the same line :(

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use Time::Piece;

 my $num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 2) {
    print "\nUsage: Modif_Log.pl inputDirectory outputDirectory\n";
exit;
}

my $inputDirectory=$ARGV[0];
my $outputDirectory=$ARGV[1];

my @liste = glob($inputDirectory."*.log*");

my $today = localtime->strftime('%d%m');

foreach my $s (@liste){
my $inbound ="";
my $outbound ="";
my $id ="";
my $encoding ="";
my $httpMethod ="";
my $contentType ="";
my $headers ="";
my $payload ="";
my $responseCode ="";
my $theAdress ="";
my $others ="";


open ( FILE, $inputDirectory.basename($s) ) || die "can't open file!";
if (-M $inputDirectory.basename($s) < 1 && $s =~ $today) {
    print "Processing ".$s."\n";
    my @lines = <FILE>;
    close (FILE);
    my $outputFileName = basename($s);
     $outputFileName =~ s/_[0-9]{6}//;
    open(my $outputFile, '>', $outputDirectory.$outputFileName) or die           "can't     open file!";
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        chomp($line);
        if ($line =~ /Inbound/i) { $inbound .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /Outbound/i) { $outbound .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^ID:/) { $id .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^Encoding :/) { $encoding .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^Http-Method:/) { $httpMethod .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^Content-Type:/) { $contentType .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^Headers:/) { $headers .= $line."|"; }
        elsif ($line =~ /^Payload:/) { $payload .= $line."|"; } 
        elsif ($line =~ /^Response-Code:/) { $responseCode .= $line."|"; }  
        elsif ($line =~ /^Address:/) { $theAdress .= $line."|"; }   
        elsif ($line !~ /--/) { $others .= $line."|"; } 
        else { ; }
    }

    if ($inbound ne "") { print $outputFile $inbound."\n"; }
    if ($outbound ne "") { print $outputFile $outbound."\n"; }
    if ($id ne "") { print $outputFile $id."\n"; }
    if ($encoding ne "") { print $outputFile $encoding."\n"; }
    if ($httpMethod ne "") { print $outputFile $httpMethod."\n"; }
    if ($contentType ne "") { print $outputFile $contentType."\n"; }
    if ($headers ne "") { print $outputFile $headers."\n"; }
    if ($payload ne "") { print $outputFile $payload."\n"; }
    if ($responseCode ne "") { print $outputFile $responseCode."\n"; }
    if ($theAdress ne "") { print $outputFile $theAdress."\n"; }
    if ($others ne "") { print $outputFile $others."\n"; }
    close $outputFile;
    print "Finished Processing ".$s."\n";
   } else {
    print $s." is older than one day\n";
   }
}
```

Can you please help me ? Perl is turning me creasy

Comment: Please consider to format the input/desired output as code, so it's easier to read. Which part of your code shoud perform the desired action?

Comment: Tha part of removing CRLf and replacing it by |

Comment: I guess you could use these regex on whole file rather than using it line by line.
`s/-//g;`
`s/\n/ | /g;`
Let me know if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove bunch of if-statements and change your forloop as following:

```
my $buf = q{};
my $last = q{};
my $sep_count = 0;
my $line_number = 0;
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    # remove CRLF, chomp only eliminate LF
    $line =~ s/\R+//;

    $line_number++;

    if ($line =~ /^-+$/) {
        # if the line is a separator
        $sep_count++;

        if ($sep_count & 1) {
            # begin sep ($sep_count is an odd number)
            $buf = $last;
        }
        else {
            # end sep ($sep_count is an even number)
            print {$outputFile} "$buf\n";
        }
    }
    else {
        if ($sep_count & 1) {
            $buf .= ' | ' . $line;
        }
        else {
            # flush $last except for the first line
            print {$outputFile} "$last\n" if $line_number != 1;
        }

        # keep last line (INFO...) to concat
        $last = $line;
    }
}

print {$outputFile} "$last\n";
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I will test this. I have a last question: How can I remove the date from the output name: WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless_260416.log -->  WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless.log

Answer (score 0):

Your list of strings are just values that must appear in a line of the input file for it to be included in the output. There is no need to store lines in different variables according to which criterion it matched

This program appears to do what you need. It builds a regular expression from the list of strings so that they can all be tested in a single match. The lines to be printed are accumulated in array `@output` and printed to the output file when the whole input file has been processed

Note that I've used `rel2abs` to append a file name to a directory. It takes account of several cases that simple string concatenation doesn't allow for, as well as making the code clearer

I haven't been able to test this except to make sure that it compiles

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;
use Time::Piece;
use File::Spec::Functions 'rel2abs';

if ( @ARGV != 2 ) {
    die "\nUsage: Modif_Log.pl input_dir output_dir\n";
}

my ( $input_dir, $output_dir ) = @ARGV;

my $today = localtime->strftime('%d%m');

my @liste = glob rel2abs( '*.log*', $input_dir );

my @wanted = (
    qr/Inbound/i,
    qr/Outbound/i,
    qr/^ID:/,
    qr/^Response-Code:/,
    qr/^Encoding :/,
    qr/^Http-Method:/,
    qr/^Content-Type:/,
    qr/^Headers:/,
    qr/^Payload:/,
    qr/^Address:/,
);

my $wanted = join '|', @wanted;
$wanted = qr/(?:$wanted)/;

for my $input_file ( @liste ) {

    unless ( -M $input_file < 1 and $input_file =~ $today ) {
        warn qq{"$input_file" is older than one day\n};
        next;
    }

    warn qq{Processing "$input_file"\n};

    open my $in_fh, '<', $input_file die qq{Unable to open "$input_file" for input: $!};

    my @output;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /$wanted/;
        chomp;
        push @output, $_;
    }

    my $output_file_name = basename($input_file);
    $output_file_name =~ s/_[0-9]{6}//;
    my $output_file = rel2abs($output_file_name, $output_dir);

    open my $out_fh, '>', $output_file
            or die qq{Unable to open "$output_file" for output: $!};

    print $out_fh join(' | ', @output), "\n";

    warn qq{Finished Processing "$input_file"\n};
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I will test this. I have a last question: How can I remove the date from the output name: WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless_260416.log --> WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless.log

Comment: That must be posted as a new question. But please think whether you really need help. It's really trivial in Perl, and if you don't make some effort to find a solution yourself then your question will be slated. Your own code has `$output_file_name =~ s/_[0-9]{6}//`, which works well enough for this string, but it's very non-specific and you may find that it makes changes that you don't expect. If you try harder yourself then you will get much better help

Comment: This doesn't work for me and thank you for your advice I'm really beginning in perl and I think I'm doing my best.

Comment: @Videoretrieval: I can't guess what you may be doing wrong. If I run this `my $s = 'WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless_260416.log'; $s =~ s/_[0-9]{6}//; print "$s\n";` then the output is `WLS-rin-a-1-GAHSTL-PROD-RAB_efluid-stateless.log` as you required